# How can I connect to Cloud Spanner emulator vie wrench CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, google-cloud-spanner, wrench

I have a locally installed Cloud Spanner emulator, running in a docker container. How can I connect to it with `wrench`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect, there are several CLI parameters to define. Here is a complete command that creates a dump from the database:

```
SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:7010 wrench --database testdb --project testproj --instance testinst load --schema_file dump.sql
```

In order to execute other commands, you may need to replace the end of this command, starting from `load` onwards.